# find element in object typescript code

Tags: html, angular, typescript, object, find

In these products I want to find only element "product_id":"4" and  display in view. Can you help please?

```
> let products= [ {"product_id":"1", "product_name":"Product1",
> "description":"Product1", "default_price":50, "lastmoduserid":"31",
> "lastmoddtm":"2018-02-06T13:26:17.000Z", "active":1},
> {"product_id":"2", "product_name":"Product2",
> "description":"Product2", "default_price":60, "lastmoduserid":"31",
> "lastmoddtm":"2018-02-06T13:35:17.000Z", "active":1},
> {"product_id":"3", "product_name":"Product3",
> "description":"Product3", "default_price":80, "lastmoduserid":"31",
> "lastmoddtm":"2018-02-06T13:35:22.000Z", "active":1},
> {"product_id":"4", "product_name":"Product4",
> "description":"Product4", "default_price":100, "lastmoduserid":"31",
> "lastmoddtm":"2018-02-06T13:25:54.000Z", "active":1},
> {"product_id":"5", "product_name":"Product5",
> "description":"Product5", "default_price":120, "lastmoduserid":"31",
> "lastmoddtm":"2018-02-06T13:35:27.000Z", "active":1} ]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array find method as shown below.

```
this.product = this.products.find(t=>t.product_id == "4");
```

---

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  products:any;
  product:any;
  json= `[ {"product_id":"1", "product_name":"Product1",
 "description":"Product1", "default_price":50, "lastmoduserid":"31",
 "lastmoddtm":"2018-02-06T13:26:17.000Z", "active":1},
 {"product_id":"2", "product_name":"Product2",
 "description":"Product2", "default_price":60, "lastmoduserid":"31",
 "lastmoddtm":"2018-02-06T13:35:17.000Z", "active":1},
 {"product_id":"3", "product_name":"Product3",
 "description":"Product3", "default_price":80, "lastmoduserid":"31",
 "lastmoddtm":"2018-02-06T13:35:22.000Z", "active":1},
 {"product_id":"4", "product_name":"Product4",
 "description":"Product4", "default_price":100, "lastmoduserid":"31",
 "lastmoddtm":"2018-02-06T13:25:54.000Z", "active":1},
 {"product_id":"5", "product_name":"Product5",
 "description":"Product5", "default_price":120, "lastmoduserid":"31",
 "lastmoddtm":"2018-02-06T13:35:27.000Z", "active":1} ]`

 constructor(){
   this.products=JSON.parse(this.json);
   this.product = this.products.find(t=>t.product_id == "4");
   console.log(this.product);
 }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ph9wtt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: search(){ this.product = this.products.find(t=>t.product_id == "4");} ---in console it's ok. But when I want to display in html, like this: <p>{{search(product_name)}}<p> --> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined. Please, how to display also in html only product_name. Thnx lot

Comment: check this demo link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krf7nj?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use array.find()

```
this.product = this.products.find(t=>t.product_id == "4");
```

make sure to declare product

```
let product :any;
```

Answer (score 1):

you only need to use the function "find", if you execute this line of code you will obtain the object in "obtainedProduct" variable if not exists inside of the array then will return "obtainedProduct" variable with value undefined.

```
let obtainedProduct =  this.products.find(x => x.product_id == "4");

console.log(obtaniedProduct);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use a filter.
this.employees = this.employees.filter(x => x.id == this.employeeId)[0];

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash find method

```
console.log(_.find(products,{"product_id":"4"}));
```